# Reusing prepared statements between dbs with identical schema

Tags: php, mysql, pdo, multi-tenant

I have a multi tenant PHP application using one database per tenant. When switching between tenants in PDO using $db->query("USE $tenant"), can prepared statements be reused between databases with identical structure? Or are they tied to a specific database? What would happen if I tried to execute a prepared statement after a switching database on the same connection?

Comment: Not likely. The execution plan is tied to the referenced tables when preparing the statements. A different database could after all have different schemas, even if table names were identical. // Might be relevant to concretize Mysql or MariaDB versions and used storage engine though.

Comment: I can't find a reference for this, but part of preparing a statement is to calculate an optimal execution plan. That plan is prepared based on real measurements of table performance and properties. These are likely to vary significantly between databases even where the schema is identical, so the plan may be sub-optimal or just plain wrong when applied to a different database. Better to recalculate the plan.

Comment: And btw, with `USE dbname` in between preparing and executing, you're not likely using real prepared statements; but just PDOs emulated ones. In which case, yes, they're reused (but only insofar as the values get interpolated behind the scenes, and literal queries are sent). At least the mysqlnd backend shouldn't drop PDOStatement handles then.

Comment: Thanks for your input! I think the reason I'm not seeing any errors is because of the emulated prepares. I didn't know they were emulated by default in mysql with PDO. Thanks for informing me. I will make sure I flush my custom statement cache when switching tenant, and try enabling native statements. With PHP 5.6 and mysql 5.5, that must be recommended?